# PHP script does not write large files to disk

Tags: php, email

I'm running a PHP script on raw emails, which writes the attachments to the disk. Every time an email is received, the raw email data is forwarded to the script, which parses the email data and extracts attachments from it.

Now this has been working just fine for small attachments. However, when the size of the attachments is around 3mb or more, the script does not write the files to the disk, or writes only about 700kb of the data. I tried changing the PHP configuration settings in `php.ini` but it's no use. What's more frustrating is that the same script runs just fine on my local machine, and extracts the attachments perfectly from raw email data.

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/zbateson/MailMimeParser) to parse the raw emails.

This is what my code looks like, which works fine for small attachments:

```
    ...

    $mailparser = new ZBateson\MailMimeParser\MailMimeParser();

    $handle = fopen($receivedfile.'.txt', 'r');

    $message = $mailparser->parse($handle);

    $attachment1 = $message->getAttachmentPart(0);
    $attachment2 = $message->getAttachmentPart(1);

    $file1contents = stream_get_contents($attachment1->getContentResourceHandle());
    $file2contents = stream_get_contents($attachment2->getContentResourceHandle());

    file_put_contents("path/to/upload/folder/image1.jpg", $file1contents);
    file_put_contents("path/to/upload/folder/image2.jpg", $file2contents);

    fclose($handle);
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: what kind of error you getting ?

Comment: ask your website's admin to increase the size if you can't do it yourself

Comment: first thing I would check is the size of $file1contents and $file2contents, so you can distinguish a disk problem (flush/sync (unlikely), overwrite (can be, maybe script launched twice)) from a stream_get_contents() problem (library problem, script ends too early, binary string is wrongly managed - maybe file writing ends on first byte '\0')

Comment: @Jack It usually happens when the size of a single attachment is 3mb+

Comment: yep.. I mean.. check it at run-time

Comment: @S.Visser The logs show these errors:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getContentResourceHandle() on a non-object`,
`exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was with my server's `/tmp` directory which had a total space of only 1mb. I changed the `sys_temp_dir` in `php.ini` to another directory and now the script works.